# Datastore and MemCache Entry Read and Pricing

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

Datastore charges by number of entities read.

1. If an entity is read from memcache, does it count as an entity read in datastore [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) and got billed?
2. If an entity is read multiple times in the same batch, does it count as one read or multiple reads?

For example, the classic Post and Tag problem, I want to look up names of tags for a list of posts,

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty()
  tag_ids = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

class Tag(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()

@ndb.tasklet
def callback(post):
  tags = yield Tag.get_multi(tag_id for tag_id in post.tag_ids)
  raise ndb.Return(tags)

qry = Post.query()
output = qry.map(callback, limit=20)
```

post01 has tag01, tag02, and post02 has tag02, tag03. In this case, tag02 was queried twice in the same batch, does tag02 count as 2 read or 1 read?

3. Is there any profile library to get number of read counted for billing, so I can figure out above questions myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by 'does it count as read'? Read from the datastore or read from the memcache?

Comment: I meant if an entity read from memcache count as an entity read in [datastore pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing). I've updated by question to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get billed for reading entities from the memcache but you have take
care on your own for putting the entities in the cache and reading from the cache.
I think this can become quite challenging when you are using a complex data model.

I am running a small application with just a few hundreds entities and when the first
user reads the data I put all the entities in the cache and all other users will get the
data from the cache.

For my other applications I am using Objectify (I am using Java) which supports putting the entities
in the Memcache (https://github.com/objectify/objectify). Maybe something similar for Python exists.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The python [ndb](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/cache) library actually manages the memcache and batch for you, and some configuration are available.